# Katharsis and JPA Annotations

Tags: jpa, katharsis

Using Katharsis in our SpringBoot Application with JPA requires to annotate JPA's @OneToMany relationships with @JsonApiToMany and similarly @ManyToOne with @JsonApiToOne. I am wondering if there is any way to avoid this duplicate annotations?
Is there any easier way to integrate Katharsis in SpringBoot + JPA Applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can build you own stereotype annotation, by example

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@JsonApiToMany
@OneToMany
public @interface CustomOneToMany{

    // ....
}
```

[Meta-annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-stereotype-annotations)

Comment: I guess ManyToOne and JsonApiToMany wont let me create meta-annotation                                                                        
-@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
-@Retention(RUNTIME)
public -@interface ManyToOne {

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a [Katharsis JPA module](https://github.com/katharsis-project/katharsis-framework/tree/master/katharsis-jpa) that you should have a look at